# Sample size needed to guess actual probability with high confidence

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose you have a weighted die with *n* sides. The actual probability of rolling any of those sides face up is varied across all the faces. How many times do you need to roll the die and record the result to know the actual probability of rolling a given face with a 99% confidence level?

I must be doing something wrong with my calculations because the answers I'm getting don't make any sense. Does anyone have advice on how I can model this problem into a formula?

Comment: I think I understand why I'm having some trouble. The formulae I've been using are for one or two groups (which by analogy would be a two sided die). For three or more groups, my new understanding is that I must either :

Comment: 1) Use Independent means by choosing the most important pair of means and calculate as if for 2 groups

Comment: 2) Use repeated measures for each group using step 1

Comment: 3) Or use Categoric data, where two groups are chosen, then collapse the outcome into a binary representation.